# Align select tags horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">   
    <div style="width: 100px;">
        <select style="width: 100%;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px;">
        <select style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 10%; float:right;" />
</div>
```

I need to align these 3 items in a line but I am getting just one select tag and input box. I have tried applying float style to both the divs and various other css styles but I am unable to get 2 select tags in a row along with right aligned text box.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No, I am just making it in a simple HTML page

Comment: giving float:left to all children divs did not solve the problem ?

Comment: No, have already tried..

Comment: can you add a fiddle demo ?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't closed your `<select></select>` and use `float:left` to align both div horizontally.

```html
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">   
   <div style="width: 100px; float:left;">
       <select style="width: 100%;" >
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
       </select>
   </div>
   <div style="width: 200px; float:left;">
       <select style="width: 100%;" >
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
       </select>
   </div>

   <input type="text" style="width: 10%; float:right;" />
</div>
```

**Update**

Or you can use `display:inline` and remove the unnecessary `div` like this :

```html
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv"> 
   <select style="width: 100px; display:inline;" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  
   <select style="width: 200px; display:inline;" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>

   <input type="text" style="width: 10%; float:right;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanku for the solution !!

Comment: The divs are unnecessary, as are floats. The default for select is display: inline.

Comment: I gave this answer so that the asker does not have to change his code to much. But you are also correct @jedifans the proper way is to use `display:inline`.

Answer (score 2):

Properly close your select tag and give the inner DIVs a `display: inline-block;` style.

```css
#comboDiv > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">
  <div style="width: 100px; ">
    <select style="width: 100%;"></select>
  </div>
  <div  style="width: 200px; ">
    <select style="width: 100%;"></select>
  </div>

  <input type="text" style="width: 10%; float:right;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">   
     <div style="width: 100px; display: inline-block">
      <select style="width: 100%;"></select>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block">
            <select style="width: 100%;"></select>
     </div>
     <input type="text" style="width: 10%; float:right;" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">   
                    <div style="width: 100px;display: inline-block;">
                        <select style="width: 100%;display: inline;">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 10%;display: inline-block;">
                        <select style="width: 100%;">
                        </select>
                </div>

                <input type="text" style="width: 10%;float:right;display: inline;">
            </div>
```

close `<select>`  using `</select>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The default width is 100% and the default styling for a select or input is display: inline.

```
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">
    <select style="width: 100px;"></select>
    <select style="width: 200px;"></select>
    <input type="text" style="width: 10%;" /> 
 </div>
```

Consider not using px for sizing but instead a relative unit like em, which will scale correctly for the user's font size.

Answer (score -1):

Just use table tag than you will get the exact output that you want.Here is the code for the same.

```
<div style="width:100%;" id="comboDiv">   
             <table>     
             <tr>
                  <td width="200px"> 
                      <div style="width: 100px; ">
                      <select style="width: 200px;" /> 
                      </div>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                    <div style="width: 200px; ">
                    <select style="width: 200px;margin_left:10em;" />
                    </div>
                   </td>
             </tr>
             </table> 
          <div>
               <input type="text" style="width: 100px; float:right;" />
          </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It will not work because `select` tag is not properly closed.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t4ydn2q6/1/ check here it will work, if you not close select tag also..How you are saying that it will not work?